# Is there a way to have a click-free install of .NET 3.5 SP1?

Tags: .net-3.5, installation

Basically I want to have our installer also install the .NET framework and any other pre-reqs as neccessary will minimal user interaction, so ideally, just run, accept license agreement and everything else is taken care of automatically.  Is this possible?  Using WiX most likely with a bootstrapper or some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the /quiet or /passive switch with the installer.